# Basic age validation from date of birth in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a date of birth in the format...

```
30-01-1983
```

I am trying to work out how to ensure that at least 16 years have passed since this date.  A basic age validation.

It seems to be defeating me but I think I am just overcomplicating it.  Does anyone have an example they can point me in the direction of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple method;

```
<?php

   $date2=date("d-m-Y");//today's date

   $date1=new DateTime("30-01-1983");
   $date2=new DateTime($date2);

   $interval = $date1->diff($date2);

   $myage= $interval->y; 

  if ($myage >= 16){ 
     echo "valid age";} 
  else{ 
     echo "Invalid age";}


  ?>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy to do manually, but PHP provides a built-in function that does the heavy lifting for you:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php